# problem with showing hidden divs using eq() and index()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that will change the opacity of elements when they are not selected.  This part of the script works fine.  However, I also want a hidden div to appear when a certain element is clicked.  I have this planned so that when the first element (is this case a picture) is clicked, the first hidden div will appear, when the second picture is clicked, the second hidden div appears.  I'm thinking it might be more useful to use classes or something like checking the opacity for a given ID on the div and then if it's < 1 showing the div.  The problem with that is, I don't know how to keep only one div visible on the page at one.  I'm tried a few things and right now this script doesn't work, but it's kinda close.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.opac {
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-opacity:0.5;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
        opacity: 0.5;
        border:thick;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.images').(function(){
        // Make all images (except this) transparent
        $('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.15}, 300);
        // Make this opaque


        $('a.images').each(function(e){
            $(this).bind('click', function(e){
                var hideIs = $(this).index();
                $('.hidden').eq(hideIs).show(250);
            });
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);
    });

});


});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="images">
<a   class="images" href="#"><img src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /></a>
<div class="hidden"   >text here</div>
<a class="images" href="#"><img  src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /></a>
<div   class="hidden">second text here</div>
<a class="images" href="#"><img  src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /></a>
<div   class="hidden">third text here
<a class="images" href="#"><img  src="../appalachia.jpg" height="133" /></a>
<div   class="hidden"  >fourth text here</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('a.images').each(function(){` instead of `$('a.images').(function(){`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't just want to use a tabs plugin?  This is the sort of behavior they are designed to accomplish, and they have all of these effects built in already.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

The jquery tools tabs plugin is only 0.9 kb!

Comment: I'll certainly have to look into that, but for my own curiosity I'd like to know where I'm wrong :)

Comment: Sorry I deleted my earlier comment - you had a mistake in your markup (the third DIV isn't closed), so my demo link didn't actually work. To see a sensible implementation of this you should look at the source of the two scripts linked above, but the best way to do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/AFLLT/

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$('.hidden').eq(hideIs).show(250);
```

use this:

```
$('.hidden.shown').removeClass('shown').hide(250);
$('.hidden').eq(hideIs).addClass('shown').show(250);
```

that'll work

What it does: It actually 'marks' previously shown div as `shown`, so before it marks another, it hides the previous one.

Comment: Your solution works for showing the divs, but it has made me lose the opacity functionality.  It also bounces several times before it actually shows the content and I have no idea why that is happening.

Comment: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dzilla/ZZm7V/, i could get the divs to show, and the divs to fade, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS ,

http://pinoytech.org/question/5571133/problem-with-showing-hidden-divs-using-eq-and-index